# Examples of groups with a certain number of Sylow 2-subgroups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a group of order 50 and $m$ be the number of Sylow 2-subgroups of $G$. What are the possible values of $m$? For each value in your list, give an example of a group $G$ for which $m$ takes that value.

By Sylow's Theorem there holds $m\equiv1$ (mod 2), so the possible values are 1, 2, 3, 5, etc. But $m\mid |G|$, i.e. $m$ divides 50. This reduces our list to 1, 5 and 25.

For $m=1$ there is the cyclic group $\mathbb Z/50\mathbb Z$, because 25 is the only element of order 2.
For $m=25$ there is $D_{2m}$ the dihedral group of order 50, because we have 25 reflections and none of the rotations can be of order 2 since 25 is odd.

But I can't seem to find an example for $m=5$. Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G=\mathbb{Z}_5\times D_{10}$.  $D_{10}$ has five distinct elements of order $2$, and these paired with the identity of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ give $5$ distinct elements of order $2$ in $G$, which give $5$ distinct Sylow $2$-subgroups.